# Getting an equivalent element in the hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

The aplication will say if the user has guessed the two combination of colors that he has introduced.

I'm using a HashMap for saving an "TwoColors" object and a boolean. The TwoColors class is the next:

```
public class TwoColors{
    public MyColor color1;
    public MyColor color2;
    public TwoColors(MyColor color1, MyColor color2){
        this.color1 = color1;
        this.color2 = color2;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TwoColors o = (TwoColors) obj;
        return color1 == o.color1 && color2 == o.color2;
    }
}
```

And MyColor is an enum

```
public enum MyColor{
     RED,BLUE,YELLOW,BROWN;
}
```

I test to put a TwoColor object key and print its value

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap<TwoColors, Boolean> hash = new HashMap<TwoColors, Boolean>();
    hash.put(new TwoColors(MyColor.RED,MyColor.BLUE),new Boolean(true));
    System.out.println(hash.get(new TwoColors(MyColor.RED,MyColor.BLUE)));
}
```

The above code outputs `null` although I have overriden TwoColors' equals method. Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: If you override equals is a good idea to override hashCode as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you override equals you should always override hashcode, if you don't do that when you try to lookup the value by calling get, your hashmap cannot find it.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) post for understanding.

Default hashcode which you can get using Eclipse:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((color1 == null) ? 0 : color1.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((color2 == null) ? 0 : color2.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

Also your equals implementation is not **Production Code**, meaning it doesn't implement it correctly. Your implementation is open for [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) since you are casting it to `MyColor` blindly, so is your implementation prone to [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

It should resemble something like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        TwoColors other = (TwoColors) obj;
        if (color1 != other.color1)
            return false;
        if (color2 != other.color2)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Before checking field value check if both references are same, check for null, check for class equality and finally check for field values.

Though Apache also has [`HashCodeBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) and [`EqualsBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

Comment: Got it, thank you. About the equals code I put it like that for making a bit more clean to read but again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the Java documentation:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the `hashCode` method whenever this method [`equals`] is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Since `MyColor` is an enum, adding this code to your class should fix it:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return color1.ordinal() + 31*color2.ordinal();
}
```